# remove a string in list

Tags: python

I have a nested list (l1) containing several lists of sentences (i) and I want to remove a particular string from the second element in (i) when the split() method is applied to it. However it seems that only half of them are removed and the rest remain.

This is what I have tried:

```
for i in l1:
    for j in i[1].split():
        if j == 'a':
            i[1].split().remove(j)
```

I have also tried to replace (j) with an empty string, but it wasn't helpful either.

example input: [[string1, This is a book], [string2, He is a tall man], ,,,]

example output: 
This is book, He is tall man

Comment: if you add some example list with strings, and the desired output, it would be easier to help you

Comment: eda - @andreihondari's answer should be the accepted answer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following code:

```
l1 = [
    [None, "This is a dog"],
    [None, "He is a tall man"],
]

for i in l1:
    sentence = i[1]
    new_sentence = []
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word == 'a':
            continue
        new_sentence.append(word)

    i[1] = " ".join(new_sentence)

print(l1)
```

will result in

```
[
    [None, 'This is dog'], 
    [None, 'He is tall man']
]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because this basically splits lines into words and ignores any word that is 'a'. The others will work only if 'a' is in the middle of the sentence. Not for something like 'A dog is a man's best friend'.

Comment: @perennial_noob have you tried running mine? It'll work just fine (with the caveat of not handling the case insensitive match as that wasn't part of the requirement)

Comment: @jmc I like your answer, very elegant

Comment: Upvoted it. I wasn't concerned about the case match as well. That can be easily fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mutate the string, so your example won't work.
But you can mutate lists, so you could split the string on whitespace, ignore `'a'` tokens and join it back together again:

```
for i in l1:
    i[1] = ' '.join(p for p in i[1].split() if p != 'a')
```

This would eat any extra whitespace in the original string, but I'm assuming that's not a concern for you here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you properly this should accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
for i in l1:
    if 'a' in i[1]:
        i[1] = i[1].replace(' a ', ' ')
```

Comment: I don't think this is what they wanted. This removes all 'a' characters, not 'a' space-separated tokens.

Comment: How python deals with list of items? When you replace it with empty string , is it removed from memory or or simply concatenated? Just want to know as i program in Java.

Comment: I agree that `.replace(' a ', ' ')` is probably what is wanted here.

Answer (score 0):

A solution a little bit more efficient I think:

```
word_search = 'a'
for i in l1:
    split_sentence = i[1].split()
    if word_search in split_sentence:
        while word_search in split_sentence:
            split_sentence.remove(word_search)
        i[1] = ' '.join(split_sentence)
```

This solution doesn't loop through the sentence and doesn't do the join in case the searched word is not found in the sentence.
This depends on the frequency of the searched word in all the sentences I guess.